# Facebook mobile workaround no longer working

Tags: facebook

Until today, I was able to add `?ref=ts` to a Facebook tab url & it would be mobile-friendly. 
Not today. Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a workaround to the workaround?

Link for example: https://www.facebook.com/microartssandbox2015/app/924049424328019/?ref=ts

Works fine on desktop. 
However, on mobile, I get:

> The page you requested cannot be display right now ...

Answer (score 0):

This has never really worked for me. The general (and well known) workaround is to use an external website and redirect to the Page on desktop. On mobile, you just stay on the external website.